# Removing Multiple Attributes in XML using XElement

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, svg, linq-to-xml

Here's my xml (or let's say svg):

```
<svg xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
inkscape:version="0.48.2 r9819"
sodipodi:docname="android.svg" viewbox="0 0 32 54">
[Some nodes below]
</svg>
```

From this one, I want to remove all the attributes where the name contains either `inkscape` or `sodipodi` (in this case, the attribute that should remain is `viewbox`.

Hope you can help me in this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is one possible this way :**

```
var raw = @"<svg xmlns:sodipodi='http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd'
xmlns:inkscape='http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape'
inkscape:version='0.48.2 r9819'
sodipodi:docname='android.svg' viewbox='0 0 32 54'>
[Some nodes below]
</svg>";
var svg = XElement.Parse(raw);
var keywords = new[] { "inkscape", "sodipodi" };
svg.Attributes()
   .Where(o => keywords.Any(k => o.Name.ToString().Contains(k)))
   .Remove();
Console.WriteLine(svg.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/etB4JX)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 32 54">
[Some nodes below]
</svg>
```

Comment: is there any way to do this in VB or C# because i'm planning to do it dynamic.

Comment: So C# is one of the option right? The above is done in C# already, what's the problem? I don't understand what you mean by *dynamic* here..

Comment: oh! it looks like javascript...or i guess i got confused.

Comment: nope. i thought the dotnetfiddle demo is jsfiddle. hehehe! will try this